# javax.crypto.Cipher update(byte[]) and doFinal(), vs doFinal(byte[])

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I have some encryption code using javax.crypto.Cipher that is working fine when I encrypt like this:

```
byte[] data = cipher.doFinal(srcdata); // srcdata is a byte[]
```

But I've run into cases where I have multiple byte[]'s that I want to encrypt as a single block.  So I tried this:

```
for (byte[] block : blocks) {
    cipher.update(block);
}

byte[] data = cipher.doFinal();
```

When I decode that result, I get this error:

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:811)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:676)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:313)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2131)
```

Reading the java docs for Cipher, it appears that should work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cipher.update(block)` returns a `byte[]` array. You are throwing it away. Send it, or write it to the file, or whatever you're supposed to do with it. The result of `cipher.doFinal()` is only a final housekeeping `byte[]` array, which you also need to send, or write, or whatever. It isn't the entire encryption.

Comment: ahh, thanks.  So I may as well not bother with the update() version of the code.
I'll have to consolidate a list of byte[]'s either way, so I may as well do it before the encryption.

Comment: That's the wrong approach. Your way requires the entire plaintext in memory at once *and* the entire ciphertext. Process a buffer-load at a time.

Comment: That would be a good way to do it, but In this particular application, I can't.
The next process needs the whole block at once.
Luckily, the largest chunk of data to deal with at once will be around 10K bytes.  So I'm not especially worried about using up all of memory.

Comment: The next process can't read the whole block at once. It reads whatever you send it. If it assumes the entire ciphertext arrives in a single read, it is improperly implemented.